# Meaning of '젖히다' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across '젖히다' in a new context today that I haven't seen before. The two example sentences are '노래 두 곡을 불러 젖혔다' and '왜 이렇게 옷을 벗어 젖혀?'. I've only ever known 젖히다 to mean 'bend back' like '뒤로 젖혀'. What does 젖히다 mean in this context and is it some sort of grammatical structure I don't know about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the auxiliary verb [젖히다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=74298).

Comment: In conversations and informal writings, we usually use a non-standard word 재끼다 instead of 젖히다.

Comment: I just figured out that 재끼다 is also a standard word.

Comment: Could you explain how you use it please? What's the nuance behind it?

Comment: I think the first sentence uses it in the sense linked to in @klmo's comment above, while the 2nd sentence uses sense 2 of the word given here: https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/ad935cd226994daf9c56f177987b1c1b. Is there more context available for these sentences?

Comment: I have found that 벗어젖히다 is actually [one word](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/a81161da6e6b49e5a790d31f4133b242). I assume this is because 벗어 젖히다 can be understood in more than one way (1. 벗어서 젖히다; 2. 벗다 + -어 젖히다). Dictionaries already show how you use the word 젖히다 and even its meaning; what exactly would you like to know beyond them?

Answer (score 2):

In my own dictionary, `젖히다` basically means to `pull out` something.

To give you some examples:

1. If you do that to your back seat or body part, it means you pull it the way you go bend back.

> - 허리를 뒤로 젖혔다.
> - 좌석을 뒤로 젖혔다.

2. When you do that to a song, you're singing that song from your heart, like it was kept in your heart, and you're eventually pulling that out heartily.

> - 노래 두 곡을 불러 젖혔다.
> - 노래 세 곡을 마음껏 불러 젖혔다.

3. When you do that to clothes you're wearing, it means you take those off toughly by grabbing it and pulling it. (Or turn it inside out)

> - 왜 이렇게 옷을 벗어 젖혀?
> - 웃통을 벗어 젖혔다.
> - 옷을 벗어 젖혔다.
> - 바지를 벗어 젖혔다.

Source: 20+ years of experience living in South Korea